# PHP call to undefined method - pdo instantiation

Tags: php, pdo, instantiation

I recently started to resurrect an old PHP4.# website. In doing so I've been trying to figure out the conversion to PDO.  After so many different attempts at PDO structure I'm getting lost and my code keeps getting more and more wild.  I believe the problem is that I'm not correctly instantiating the pdo class but have failed using several different methods.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DBInsert::__construct() in /home/folder/database/insert.php:36

mysqlhelper.php

```
<?php

class MySQLHelper
{
    private $link;
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    var $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $db   = 'dbname';
        $user = 'username';
        $pass = 'supersecret';
        $port = '1111';
                
        $options = [
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
                
        try {
             $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;port=$port";
             $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
             return $this->pdo;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
             throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
             echo "Connection failed";
        }
        
    }


    function __destruct() 
    {
        // Closing connection
        $this->pdo = null;
    }
    
    public function query($query)
    {
        // Performing SQL query
        $result = $this->pdo->query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }
```

insert.php

```
    <?php
    include "../helpers/mysqlhelper.php";
    
    class DBInsert
    {
        private $helper;
        private $nations;
        private $nations_updated;
        private $stagedslots;
        private $stagednations_new; // nations that need to be inserted
        private $stagednations_old; // nations that need to be updated
        var $pdo;
    
    //this function was previously called __construct() prior to my 11/22/20 updates
        function somethingelse()
        {
            $this->helper = new MySQLHelper();
            $this->stagedslots = array();
            $this->nations_updated = array();
            $this->nations = array();
    
            $q = "SELECT * FROM `nations`";
            $result = $this->helper->query($q);
            $result = $this->helper->getResultArray($result);
            foreach ($result as $val)
            {
                $this->nations[$val["id"]] = $val;
            }
        }
    
        public function clearSlots()
        {
            $sql = "DELETE FROM `slots`;";
            $object = new MySQLHelper;
            $object->__construct();
line 36     $stmt = $this->__construct()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
```

For line 36 I've also tried $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql); which yields errors also.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: "_//this function was previously called __contruct()_" Was it called `__contruct()` or `__construct()`?

Comment: Not sure if `var $pdo;` is valid in PHP

Comment: @kerbh0lz it is valid, but not recommended.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the info

Comment: `var $pdo` is doing the job of `public $pdo` in this context, which is how it would usually be written.

Comment: What is the purpose of `DBInsert` class? Where do you define `__construct()`?

Comment: Your class `MySQLHelper` doesn't follow the best practices. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo You might be better off just using a pre-made DB abstraction library. I highly recommend https://github.com/paragonie/easydb

Comment: @kerbh0lz it was __construct corrected the comment typo! The function was named the same as the class which apparently was an old practice that is frowned upon so I renamed it something random

Comment: @Dharman it's defined only in the class in the helper file

Comment: But then what is the purpose of `$this->__construct()`? Your DBInsert class doesn't have a constructor, but even if it had why are you calling it there?

Comment: I guess my thought is that the function would need to call to create a connection. It gets the function to create the connection from the mysqlhelper file class which is also used in other files not just the insert.php

So insert.php includes mysqlhelper.php, uses the constructor function from there if it's called.  I have no idea if that helps to explain it that way.

Comment: At the moment your class `MySQLHelper` is completely useless. You can remove it. You can use PDO directly but then thr problem is that you have a hard dependency. Instead, you should use dependency injection and take PDO instance as a parameter to your `DBInsert` class. Of course then the nest question is what is `DBInsert` for... but that is a separate topic

Answer (score 0):

```
 $object = new MySQLHelper;
            $object->__construct();
            $stmt = $this->__construct()->prepare($sql);
```

You are writing the same thing three times here:

You make a new object `$object` and then you do not need to call `__construct` because by making the object it automatically calls the constructor already.

```
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `slots`;";
    $object = new MySQLHelper; //automaticcally calls the constructor
    $stmt = $object->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close(); // close connection.
```

[**READ THIS**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have tried it so many ways I did wind up with a redundant mess and thus the post. I made that adjustment to clean up the duplication and have an updated error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MySQLHelper::prepare() in /home/folder/database/insert.php:35

Do I need to make the object line something like:
$object = new $this->MySQLHelper 

Guess I don't understand if it's not reaching the class from mysqlhelper.php or if MySQLHelper class doesn't like the prepare function.

Comment: Yeah I've been in that guide for a few days now. Just not fully understanding it. Thanks again.